# Problem with Generic Function in Rust with integers and floats. Working through Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs in Rust

Tags: rust, sicp

I have this so far.  And I can not find a way to deal with the comparison with `good_enough`.  I am working through Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs and I would like to conform best I can to the practices in the book.  Scheme is easy.  I've got that.  Just need help making my rust code more general.

Playground: [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a71b494fed7210e98ac96230745e0851)

```
use num_traits::cast::FromPrimitive;
use std::cmp::PartialOrd;
use std::ops::{Add, Div, Mul, Sub};

fn square<T: Mul<Output = T> + Copy>(x: T) -> T {
    x * x
}

fn average<T: Add<Output = T> + Div<Output = T> + FromPrimitive>(x: T, y: T) -> T {
    (x + y) / FromPrimitive::from_usize(2).unwrap()
}

fn abs<T: PartialOrd + Mul<Output = T> + FromPrimitive>(x: T) -> T {
    if x < FromPrimitive::from_usize(0).unwrap() {
        x * FromPrimitive::from_isize(-1).unwrap()
    } else {
        x
    }
}

fn good_enough<T: Copy + Sub<Output = T> + Mul<Output = T> + FromPrimitive + PartialOrd>(guess: T, x: T) -> bool {
    abs(square(guess) - x) < 0.0001
}

fn main() {
    println!("Average or {} and {} is {}", 4, 2, average(4, 2));
    println!("Square of {} is {}", average(4, 2), square(average(4, 2)));
    println!("Absolute Value of {} is {}", -4.5, abs(-4.5));
    println!("Test of good_enough: {}",good_enough(3,9));
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:22:30
   |
21 | fn good_enough<T: Copy + Sub<Output = T> + Mul<Output = T> + FromPrimitive + PartialOrd>(guess: T, x: T) -> bool {
   |                - this type parameter
22 |     abs(square(guess) - x) < 0.0001
   |                              ^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found floating-point number
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                        found type `{float}`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `sqrt`.
```

Finished sqrt project for those interested in Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (Chapter 001)!

```
use std::cmp::PartialOrd;
use std::convert::Into;
use std::ops::{Add, Div, Mul, Sub};

use num_traits::cast::FromPrimitive;

fn square<T>(x: T) -> T
    where T: Mul<Output=T> + Copy
{
    x * x
}

fn average<T>(x: T, y: T) -> T
    where T: Add<Output=T> + Div<Output=T> + FromPrimitive
{
    (x + y) / FromPrimitive::from_usize(2).unwrap()
}

fn abs<T>(x: T) -> T
    where T: PartialOrd + Mul<Output=T> + FromPrimitive
{
    if x < FromPrimitive::from_usize(0).unwrap() {
        x * FromPrimitive::from_isize(-1).unwrap()
    } else {
        x
    }
}

fn improve<T>(guess: T, x: T) -> T
    where T: Add<Output=T> + Div<Output=T> + FromPrimitive + Copy
{
    average(guess, x / guess)
}

fn good_enough<T:>(guess: T, x: T) -> bool
    where T: Copy + Sub<Output=T> + Mul<Output=T> + FromPrimitive + PartialOrd + Into<f64>
{
    let new_guess = guess.into();
    let y = x.into();
    abs(square(new_guess) - y) <= FromPrimitive::from_f64(0.00000000000001).unwrap()
}

fn sqrt_iter<T>(guess: T, x: T) -> f64
    where T: Copy + Add<Output=T> + Div<Output=T> + Mul<Output=T> + Sub<Output=T> + PartialOrd + FromPrimitive + Into<f64>
{
    let mut updated_guess = guess.into();
    // loop only because I had some stack overflows during testing
    let y = x.into();
    loop {
        if good_enough(updated_guess, y) {
            return updated_guess;
        } else {
            updated_guess = improve(updated_guess, y);
        }
    }
}

fn my_sqrt<T>(x: T) -> f64
    where T: Copy + Add<Output=T> + Div<Output=T> + Mul<Output=T> + Sub<Output=T> + PartialOrd + FromPrimitive + Into<f64>
{
    sqrt_iter(FromPrimitive::from_f64(1.0).unwrap(), x)
}

fn main() {
    println!("Average or {} and {} is {}", 4, 2, average(4, 2));
    println!("Square of {} is {}", average(4, 2), square(average(4, 2)));
    println!("Absolute Value of {} is {}", -4.5, abs(-4.5));
    println!("Test of good_enough: {}", good_enough(3, 9));
    println!("See improve in action guess: {} x:{} outcome:{}", 2, 9, improve(2, 9));
    println!("Sqrt of {} is {}", 7921, my_sqrt(7921));
}
```

Output:

```
Average or 4 and 2 is 3
Square of 3 is 9
Absolute Value of -4.5 is 4.5
Test of good_enough: true
See improve in action guess: 2 x:9 outcome:3
Sqrt of 7921 is 89
```

Finished playground: [Final Playground!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=22f25601fa2f19876c02660ef355920d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rust
fn good_enough<T: Copy + Sub<Output = T> + Mul<Output = T> + FromPrimitive + PartialOrd>(guess: T, x: T) -> bool {
    abs(square(guess) - x) < FromPrimitive::from_f64(0.0001).unwrap()
}
```

You need to convert `0.0001` to `T` because `T` only implements [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html).
Or you can make `T: PartialOrd<f64>` but it'll make the function not able to accept integer types.

Comment: That was it.  I guess that is what I get trying to work on this outside of Jetbrains.  I started plugging in your answer at home and it started popping up what I thought I had previously entered in on REPL.it but guess I had a typo and didn't find it.  Hope it helps someone else.